# NumberFormatException for TestNG suite

Tags: java, xml, testng

I am trying to run my Selenium tests through the command line. To achieve it, I have created a sample class with several tests, and a *testng.xml* file.

I am running following commands one after another in the command line:

```
d: 
cd D:\Yes\selenium\sel_mock_aut_tests\Nothing
set pp=D:\Yes\selenium\sel_mock_aut_tests\Nothing
set classpath=%pp%\bin;%pp%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %pp%\ATestNG.xml
```

This results in the following error:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
```

My *testng.xml* files looks like this (and is named *ATestNG.xml*):

```
<suite name="MyTests" verbose="1.0">
<test name="BatExecution">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestNGOperations.RunUsingBatFile" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [the first example of a suite](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) in the TestNG documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

What is causing your error is `verbose="1.0"`. TestNG tries to parse `1.0` to an `int`, causing the exception.

You probably want `verbose="1"` there instead.

---

As a side note, the TestNG documentation is rather sparse about the `verbose` attribute. [This blogpost](http://seleniumone-by-arun.blogspot.se/2013/05/158-understanding-usage-of-verbose.html) does a good job at explaining what values the attribute can have:

> Before understanding the usage of verbose attribute, first you have to know the values it can accept. Verbose attribute can takes values from 1 to 10 as shown below:
>
> verbose="1"
>   verbose="2"
>   verbose="3"
>   verbose="4"
>   verbose="5"
>   verbose="6"
>   verbose="7"
>   verbose="8"
>   verbose="9"
>   verbose="10"
>
> If we specify the verbose attribute with smaller number, then the test results log details in the Eclipse IDE -> 'console' window will be less. But if you want to get more details and want  to see more clarity on the test results log details in the Eclipse IDE -> 'console' window then you have to assign larger number to the verbose attribute.

Of course, this does not only apply to Eclipse, it is a TestNG configuration.